# Create counter column based on values in 2 dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to create a counter column based on row values in 2 dataframe columns, represented here at Col1 and Col2.

An example of the dataset is as follows:

```
Col1    Col2
 a       0
 a       0
 a       0
 a       1
 a       0
 a       0
 a       0
 a       1
 a       1
 b       0
 b       0
 b       1
 b       1
 b       0
 b       0
```

Where Col1 is an identification variable, and where I want the counter to start over when a new identification variable comes across (so when 'a' switches to 'b', the counter returns to 0).

Col2 is an indication of a new input in the data. When a 1 arises, a new input arises, and the 0s after that correspond to measurements in that input. Each time a 1 arises, I want the counter variable to increment 1. Each time the 1 returns to a 0 (and vice versa), I also want the counter to increment 1. Based on the above dataset, I want the output to look like the following in Col3:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
 a       0       0
 a       0       0
 a       0       0
 a       1       1
 a       0       2
 a       0       2
 a       0       2
 a       1       3
 a       1       4
 b       0       0
 b       0       0 
 b       1       1
 b       1       2
 b       0       3
 b       0       3
```

So basically every time Col2 switches from a 0 to a 1, and each time a 1 arises, I want the counter to increment. Each time a 0 is present in Col2, I want the counter to remain the same value. And every time Col1 changes to a new ID (in this case, from 'a' to 'b') I want the counter to start over at 0.

I've been mainly doing this with conditional statements, but there are a ton of them and I'm looking to run this on a large dataset, which would take hours to run. Is there a quick and easy way to run something like this, with these conditions on both columns? Or does anyone have suggestions on transformations to this data that would make running a categorization like this easier?

I understand that this is a slightly confusing request, so please let me know if there is anything I can do to provide more clarity into what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.assign(Col4=df1.groupby('Col1').Col2.apply(lambda x: 
     pd.Series(pd.np.r_[False,(x[1:]==1) |(x.values[1:] != x.values[:-1])].cumsum())).values)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     a     0     0     0
1     a     0     0     0
2     a     0     0     0
3     a     1     1     1
4     a     0     2     2
5     a     0     2     2
6     a     0     2     2
7     a     1     3     3
8     a     1     4     4
9     b     0     0     0
10    b     0     0     0
11    b     1     1     1
12    b     1     2     2
13    b     0     3     3
14    b     0     3     3
```

Comment: @CSlater you should consider accepting it as the solution then. ie you click on the tick against the solution. You also upvote. Thanks